# Does SQL Server 2014 support functions such as ISNOTNULL()?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, null, sql-server-2014

dont you know how to change ISNULL() to ISNOTNULL() in MS SQL? 
Something like IFNULL?

I need to do it in one step.

```
Set @EMAILhtml = @CSS + @TEXT1 + isnull(@TEXT1,'') +  isnull(@table1,'') + isnull(@text2,'') + isnull(@table2,'')  + @TEXT3
```

But I need something like

```
Set @EMAILhtml = @CSS + @TEXT1 + isNOTnull(@TEXT1,'') +  isnull(@table1,'') + isnull(@text2,'') + isnull(@table2,'')  + @TEXT3
```

Thanks.

Comment: This does not make sense. `isnull` is the same as `coalesce` but for 2 parameters. It is just a default value in case of a NULL. e.g. isnull (x,'Hey! x was null!'). similar to `case when x is not null then x else 'Hey! x was null!' end`

Answer (score 2):

I think you've got something wrong:

`ISNULL()` is used to set a default value in case of `NULL`

```
DECLARE @v1 VARCHAR(10)='test';
SELECT ISNULL(@v1,'default') --returns `test`;
SET @v1=NULL;
SELECT ISNULL(@v1,'default') --returns `default`;
```

Checking for `NULL` is done with `IS NULL`. The opposite is `IS NOT NULL`

```
DECLARE @v1 VARCHAR(100)=NULL;
SELECT CASE WHEN @v1 IS NULL THEN 'v1 is null' END
```

The third option in this context is `NULLIF()`, which returns `NULL` if a condition is fullfilled

```
DECLARE @v1 VARCHAR(10)='test';
SELECT NULLIF(@v1,'test'); --returns NULL, because @v1='test'
```

And last but not least there is `COALESCE()`. It will return the first non-null value of a list of paramters:

```
DECLARE @v1 VARCHAR(10)=NULL;
DECLARE @v2 VARCHAR(10)=NULL;
DECLARE @v3 VARCHAR(10)='test';
SELECT COALESCE(@v1,@v2,@v3); --returns 'test'
```

Answer (score 1):

are you referring to `IS NULL` and `IS NOT NULL`?
as in -

```
select * from t where x is null
select * from t where x is not null
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why are you trying to retrieve if is not null this way. The `ISNULL()` function help to substitute a `NULL` value to a default one

I suggest to try something like that:

`CASE WHEN column IS NOT NULL THEN 'Hey is not null' ELSE 'Sorry, is null!' END`

Hope this could help.

Answer (score 0):

```
 set @TEXT1 = (case when @table1 is null then null else @TEXT1 end)
```

before the final set